# What is considered an endpoint hit/utterance?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

In my LUIS dashboard there are currently 6 registered endpoint hits. Sometimes a connection from my own computer is considered an endpoint hit and occasionally the messages I sent to the bot end up under **Review Endpoint Utterances**.

What triggers the Endpoint Hit and the Endpoint Utterance? It seems to trigger very randomly at this point.

I'm using a DirectLine channel to reach my bot running in Azure through this local HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An endpoint hit is a call to LUIS API. So everytime your bot is using LUIS, it is an endpoint hit.

There seems to be a bug in LUIS portal about that, I already saw that my endpoint hits was still 0 but my bot was successfully calling LUIS.

Comment: I suppose it's the same for endpoint utterances too then? I have no issues calling LUIS through my bot either.

Comment: I don't know the exact rule in LUIS Portal to suggest `Endpoint Utterances` to review, but yes I saw that not every item sent to the API is suggested (that would be horrible if every call was suggested in an intent!)

Comment: The dashboard doesn't immediately show endpoint hits. If you want an accurate count of endpoint hits, create a free LUIS subscription, assign the key on the publish page, then check the key usage in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

LUIS does not log every endpoint call to  "reviewing endpoint utterances" section, it logs only those utterance which are  received via the LUIS HTTPS endpoint that LUIS is unsure of. so this is not a bug in the LUIS portal. It is developed this way.  Usually these utterances gets low scoring intent. LUIS provide chance to the user to correct the utterance intent so that after training LUIS can give correct result.